# How do I put a game on miniclip or addinctinggames?

Tags: java, android, distribution

I finished making a java game recently, and I would like to put it on a website such as Miniclip.com or AddictingGames. How would I do this?

I have one more question. I know these sites could run Flash games, but what about Java games? If they can't, is there any other website analogous to those that would?

My reason for this is that I am planning on launching this game on Android, and I would like to get some feedback for this game and have some people be familiar with the game before it launches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addicting games has an upload page [here](http://www.addictinggames.com/game/upload.jsp), looks like the mobile submission process is via email.

Same with Mini clip, they have a [developers page](http://corporate.miniclip.com/page/view/developers), and you'll need to email them for a mobile submission.

Neither looks like they do Java for PC, but both appear to do Android games.

[Desura](http://www.desura.com/development) can offer what you want with a Java PC game. As a bonus they also have a beta service for your game, and that's what it looks like you want first.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know about if Newgrounds satisfies my specifications?

Comment: I believe Newgrounds is flash only, I don't know of any of those websites that do Java for PC.